# Extending twitter bootstrap to be contained within a parent element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, less

I'm probably about to regret what I am trying to do, but hear me out.  I want to incorporate the bootstrap css libary into an existing drupal theme which powers many sites so I can use bootstrap to generate clean forms.  My problem is that I dont want the bootstrap css to negatively affect other portions of my sites.  I was trying to find a way to pull out just the elements of bootstrap that I needed, and the 'customize bootstrap' page on getbootstrap.com is great for this.  However, it doens't help me keep the bootstrap css 'constrained' to just the areas that I want.

What I really want to do is to use teh bootstrap forms.less file, but with the entire file encapsulated into a parent class (like, .bootstrap), so for example, instead of having rules like this:

`fieldset { whatever }`

instead, all the rules would look like:

`.bootstrap fieldset {whatever}`

Of course, its possible for me to go into the bootstrap source and manually edit the files to give them the .bootstrap class, but then I have to manually keep updating my copy of bootstrap whenever an update comes.

My question is, is there a way (using less/sass?) to generate a version of bootstrap that isn't 'global' in scope, so you can say 'these rules only apply to this parent selector'?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Anything at all?  Done any research into LESS or Sass to see how this might be done?

Comment: yes there's a way to do this in LESS and Sass. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149266/prefixing-all-selectors-for-twitter-bootstrap-in-less

Comment: sorry guys.  i googled, just not well.  thank you.