# Import Bootstrap in a sub-container and make grids classes properly generated

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap to develop a Wordpress plugin. The fact is that many plugin or themes can also use their own stylesheets. So, to make sure that my bootstrap styles will only apply on the containers generated by my plugin, I import the bootstrap less inside some containers, like so :

```
.my-plugin-container,
.my-plugin-menu {
    @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

It works for most of the components, but I have to re-adapt some things, especially the grids. In this case, the generated CSS for grids is not correct and will be :

```
@media (min-width: 1140px)
.my-plugin-container .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12,
.my-plugin-menu .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
     float: left;
}

.my-plugin-container .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xl-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xl-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xl-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xl-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xl-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xl-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xl-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xl-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xl-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xl-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xl-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12, .col-xl-12,
.my-plugin-menu .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xl-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xl-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xl-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xl-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xl-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xl-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xl-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xl-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xl-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xl-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xl-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12, .col-xl-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
```

To make this works, and to get my main container classes prepended on each `.col-@{class}-@{index}`, I modified the following mixins.
```

```
.make-grid-columns() {
  .col(@default: ''){
    position: relative;
    // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
    min-height: 1px;
    // Inner gutter via padding
    padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
    padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  }
  // Common styles for all sizes of grid columns, widths 1-12
  .col-xs(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-xs-@{index}";
    @{item} { .col(); }
    .col-xs((@index + 1));
  }
  .col-sm(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-sm-@{index}";
    @{item} { .col(); }
    .col-sm((@index + 1));
  }
  .col-md(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-md-@{index}";
    @{item} { .col(); }
    .col-md((@index + 1));
  }
  .col-lg(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-lg-@{index}";
    @{item} { .col(); }
    .col-lg((@index + 1));
  }
  .col-xl(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-xl-@{index}";
    @{item} { .col(); }
    .col-xl((@index + 1));
  }
  .col-xs(1);
  .col-sm(1);
  .col-md(1);
  .col-lg(1);
  .col-xl(1);
}

.float-grid-columns(@class) {
  .col(@index) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // initial
    @item: ~".col-@{class}-@{index}";
    @{item} {
      float: left;
    }
    .col((@index + 1));
  }
  .col(1); // kickstart it
}
```

This is now working, and I have all my containers classes prepended to the bootstrap cols classes, so, even if the Wordpress sites is using others bootstrap styles, I can ensure that mine will be used for my container, and not the one from the theme, or another plugin.
***My question is : Do you have a better solution than my mixin modification to make this work ?***

EDIT : This question is not the same as the one posted in [Prefixing all selectors for twitter bootstrap in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149266/prefixing-all-selectors-for-twitter-bootstrap-in-less/19812854#19812854)
the answer provided in this post cannot work for me. i'm not using precompiled bootstrap. i'm using bootstrap from LESS, not from a CSS compiled file. I also need variables and mixins to develop my theme. Wrapping bootstrap LESS in a container generate wrong CSS rules from some mixins, especially the grids. I get `.my-plugin-container .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, ....` instead of `.my-plugin-container .col-lg-1, .my-plugin-container .col-lg-2, ....`. I understand that this issue should not happen if I had imported bootstrap as CSS, but that's not the case for me. I need to work with bootstrap LESS, not a precompiled one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19812854/2712740

Comment: Euuuh, what ? Can you please explain this @seven-phases-max ? I don't see how prefixing bootstrap classes would fix the problem. Prefixing bootstrap will make any JS component to not work anymore. Prefixing would work only if Bootstrap provide us a grunt/gulp compilator that allow us to add a prefix on all classes, including JS files.

Comment: And, additionally, the example you are providing is exactly what i'm doing. See the first block of code pasted in my question. It's exactly the same as the example you provided.

Comment: Note : I also tried to use `@import (reference)` but it also doesn't work for JS components, because all classes will be manually redefined or renamed.

Comment: "See the first block of code pasted in my question. It's exactly the same as the example you provided." - No, it is not. Look at the code in the linked answer once more. As for JS compatibility, it's not a problem to generate intermediate css for grid staff only.

Comment: @seven-phases-max im not sure you understood my pbm. I don't see how importing a bootstrap CSS interpreted as LESS could help me. I don't use CSS bootstrap. I use LESS. I also need bootstrap mixins... I also need the whole LESS source code to define my variables. I do not a create a theme by overriding CSS bootstrap rules one by one ... This is a so huge work, and my theme would be broken on each BS update (even if BS is going on v4 w/ SASS). So yes, the code you provide is the same : you wrap bootstrap inside a container. And no, I can't use this, because the code is compiled

Comment: @seven-phases-max Question edited. your answer should work for someone importing bootstrap CSS instead of bootstrap LESS. That's not my case. This answer can't work for me.

Comment: I understand your problem perfectly. As I already mentioned: " it's not a problem to generate intermediate css for grid staff only.". I.e. compile just Bootstrap "grid.less" (incl. required imports) then import resulting css into a wrapper of interest. (This no way affects importing the rest of Bootstrap as Less etc.). That's it (it's two compiler passes instead of usual one but this is the easiest way to get it w/o modifying original BS code).

Comment: Ah, ok I see. Creating/compiling an intermediate CSS that contain only structural elements is an accepted answer finally ;) I didn't get the fact that I could generate for example a bootstrap-utilities.css file containing only the grids stuff. This could work, thanks a lot for that explanations @seven-phases-max